# Design rest API with Criteria like filter

Tags: rest, spring-rest

I want to design a rest api something similar to below. but this  will require lot of work on server side, is there any generic framework/library available for handling this? Any suggestion is welcome..

```
GET /app/items?finished_at=ge:15:30&finished_at=lt:16:00
{
  "items": [
    {"id": "item1", "started_at": "2016-10-10T15:00Z",
     "finished_at": "2016-10-10T15:30Z"}
  ]
}
```

For example:

I have a search cafeteria as below

```
creation_date>= 10-Jan-2017 and creation_date <= 14-Jan-2017 and (user_role in (admin,read-only,sales) or user_id in (12,3,4))
```

Comment: Yes there are plenty. Try this one: start.spring.io

Comment: @Stipson Cat i din't get you

Comment: Your question is some kind of incomplete, so you get a very general comment in reply. If you want to develop a rest endpoint, use spring boot rest and if you want to use database access select JPA as well. You will have to write some code

Comment: Thanks ! i have explained a bit more with example.